# vscode tener varios iconos que abran varios proyectos diferentes

Tags: vscode

Estoy trabajando en dos proyectos y cada vez que tengo que cambiar de una ubicación a otra es un autentico coñazo entonces he pensado en tener dos iconos que abran dos ubicaciones diferentes y buscando un poco encontré este parámetro:  `--folder-uri` por ello
estoy intentado colocar el parámetro `--folder-uri "C:\xampp\htdocs\etiquetas"` en el icono en el apartado de destino abra esa ubicación u otra cualquiera para así poder hacer varios iconos, no es viable la opción de tener las dos carpetas abiertas.